# Rule's order does matter in TreeTop?

Tags: ruby, treetop

I am just starting to use TreeTop to do parsing works. The following is the snippets that puzzles me:

```
grammar Fortran
    rule integer
        [1-9] [0-9]*
    end

    rule id
        [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]*
    end
end

parser = FortranParser.new
ast = parser.parse('1')
```

The result `ast` is:

```
[SyntaxNode offset=0, "1", SyntaxNode offset=1, ""]
```

But when I place `rule id` above `rule integer`, the result is `nil`. So what is the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I just figured out where is wrong!!! There should be a top rule that includes other rules, which is placed as the first rule:

```
grammar Fortran
    rule statement
        ( id / integer )* {
            def content
                elements.map { |e| e.content }
            end
        }
    end

    rule id
        [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]* {
            def content
                [:id, text_value]
            end
        }
    end

    rule integer
        [1-9] [0-9]* {
            def content
                [:integer, text_value]
            end
        }
    end
end

parser = FortranParser.new
ast = parser.parse('1')
```

Then the result is

```
[[:integer, "1"]]
```